# Modular Quicksort Implementation (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, quicksort

I'm trying to write a class that contains an array of numbers that you can sort with a function *myArray.quicksort()*.
When creating a new Objekt of *Array* I pass the constructor the length and then fill it:

```
public: int Items[];

    /*-- Constructor --*/
    Array(int n){
        length = n;
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            int zahl;
            Items[length];
            cout << "Item" << i << ": ";
            cin >> number;
            Items[i] = number;
        }
     ...
```

Right after creating the Array this function to print it out works just fine:

```
void Array::show(){
    for(int i=0; i<this->length; i++){
        cout << this->Items[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

However after I try to sort it it prints out nonsense:

```
void Array::quickSort(int left, int right){
  int i=left, j=right;
  int tmp;
  int pivot = this->Items[(left + right) / 2];

  while(i <= j){
        while (this->Items[i] > pivot)
              i++;
        while (this->Items[j] < pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = this->Items[i];
              this->Items[i] = this->Items[j];
              this->Items[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };

  if (left < j)
        quickSort(left, j);
  if (i < right)
        quickSort(i, right);
}
```

I'm sure I totally mix up something with the array pointers..
But I can't seem to find a solution for it. 
Where is the big flaw here?

Comment: If you want to implement your own array you can't have arrays, you must use pointers and dynamically allocate (with `new[]`) the memory. Don't forget to `delete[]` the memory, and also read about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). And remember: While arrays and pointers often can be used interchangeably, arrays and pointers are still different and need to be declared differently (i.e. you can't have `int arr[]` and use `new[]` to allocate memory for it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard C++ does not have [flexible array members](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/flexible-array-member/) (like C99 has).

You don't need your `Array` class, use [`std::vector<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead (or perhaps [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) with C++11 if the array length is a compile time constant)

If you want to declare your `Array`  class containing `Items`, follow the hints in the comment of [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg), learn about the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) (in C++11, it became the rule of five), so declare:

```
int *Items;
```

in your class, then initialize it with

```
Items = new int[n];
```

in its constructor[s], and destroy it with

```
delete [] Items;
```

in your destructor.